# PhoneGap getDirectory() returning undefined

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Im running cordova-2.6.0 PhoneGap in Android.
Im facing a problem to return boolean in my function.
Why my function returning undefined and how to fix it? Any Idea??

```
function isDir(target) {
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory(target, { create: false, exclusive: false },
        function(entry) {
            return true;
        },
        function(entry) {
            return false;
        }
    );
});
```

}

When I call it something like `alert(isDir('Dir Name'))`
It returns undefined.
Why this happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: There is no return statement in isDir(). Your subject is wrong as it is not getDirectory() but getDir().

Comment: When I use alert(true) instead of return statement, it works.
How can I make it return boolean?

Comment: `use alert(true) instead of return statement` ? I cannot follow you. You used `alert(isDir('Dir Name'))` before. And you can make isDir() to return a boolean by adding a return statement to it. At the moment isDir() does not return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this my own!
It had not enough permission to get FileSystem.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```